# How would I know if I’ve been hacked on a iphone 7+

Tags: iphone, ios, hacking

How do I know if my iPhone 7+  was hacked an what was used to hack i

Comment: Why do you suspect that your phone was hacked?

Answer (score 2):

It fully depends on what kind of hack it is.

Some hacks are not detectable by non-experts. Some will manifest in higher battery usage, higher network usage, apps not working as they used to or similar. However this symptoms can be caused by other, more likely, circumstances.

Take into account that it is very unusual for an ordinary user to have his iPhone hacked. Especially if you're only running Apple and App Store software, and haven't jailbroken the phone.